# Is there an alternative to pivotlonger function in R?

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm working on this microtiter data set, where I have measurements of a strain growing in a 96-well plate with different concentrations of DNase. I have taken the average of all the replicates and made the excel csv file, but also calculated the standard deviations in order to make error bars for my graph. I have a similar data set, but instead of time, I just have three different strains measured at different concentrations. I will insert the code below. Now, this code does not work for this data set, and I need to figure out a way to pivot the data set longer, but have the standard deviations tied to the mean values. I have tried the gather function also, but then it will duplicate the values, which is not what I want
Please help with suggestions or tell me if my code is wrong

[Data set imported from excel that has not been manipulated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtjzD.png)

[Data set form excel that has not been manipulated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiEPz.png)

[Data set with SD replicates, which is not wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJMtA.png)

[Other data set that my code worked on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwHan.png)

```
dput(B690DNaseI)
structure(list(Time = c("00:15", "00:30", "00:45", "01:00", "01:15", 
"01:30", "01:45", "02:00", "02:15", "02:30", "02:45", "03:00", 
"03:15", "03:30", "03:45", "04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", 
"05:00", "05:15", "05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", 
"06:45", "07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", 
"08:30", "08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", 
"10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", 
"12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", 
"13:45", "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", 
"15:30", "15:45", "16:00"), LB = c(0.08775, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 
0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 
0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.08775, 
0.088, 0.08775, 0.088, 0.08825, 0.08825, 0.08825, 0.0885, 0.0885, 
0.08875, 0.08875, 0.08925, 0.0895, 0.09, 0.09025, 0.09075, 0.0915, 
0.092, 0.0935, 0.0945, 0.0955, 0.09725, 0.09925, 0.101, 0.10175, 
0.10525, 0.10825, 0.1105, 0.113, 0.117, 0.121, 0.12375, 0.12625, 
0.1305, 0.13275, 0.1375, 0.139, 0.145, 0.15025, 0.15175, 0.1585, 
0.1655, 0.1705, 0.17425, 0.18125), C0 = c(0.16925, 0.20775, 0.23975, 
0.268, 0.29225, 0.316, 0.3385, 0.359, 0.38125, 0.401, 0.423, 
0.444, 0.4645, 0.48725, 0.51125, 0.53525, 0.563, 0.59825, 0.6375, 
0.682, 0.729, 0.7835, 0.84725, 0.8935, 0.9555, 0.9975, 1.0475, 
1.094, 1.141, 1.19, 1.2285, 1.27225, 1.30925, 1.34475, 1.3725, 
1.39875, 1.4255, 1.457, 1.47825, 1.495, 1.51825, 1.52675, 1.54475, 
1.57025, 1.57975, 1.5865, 1.60025, 1.60975, 1.6155, 1.6145, 1.625, 
1.63225, 1.63125, 1.6385, 1.63625, 1.6435, 1.63825, 1.63925, 
1.64625, 1.64225, 1.6405, 1.64475, 1.648, 1.6465), C10 = c(0.16925, 
0.20775, 0.23975, 0.268, 0.29225, 0.316, 0.3385, 0.359, 0.38125, 
0.401, 0.423, 0.444, 0.4645, 0.48725, 0.51125, 0.53525, 0.563, 
0.59825, 0.6375, 0.682, 0.729, 0.7835, 0.84725, 0.8935, 0.9555, 
0.9975, 1.0475, 1.094, 1.141, 1.19, 1.2285, 1.27225, 1.30925, 
1.34475, 1.3725, 1.39875, 1.4255, 1.457, 1.47825, 1.495, 1.51825, 
1.52675, 1.54475, 1.57025, 1.57975, 1.5865, 1.60025, 1.60975, 
1.6155, 1.6145, 1.625, 1.63225, 1.63125, 1.6385, 1.63625, 1.6435, 
1.63825, 1.63925, 1.64625, 1.64225, 1.6405, 1.64475, 1.648, 1.6465
), C20 = c(0.19975, 0.2285, 0.2555, 0.28525, 0.318, 0.3545, 0.3865, 
0.4155, 0.45, 0.482, 0.50825, 0.52975, 0.55625, 0.58325, 0.604, 
0.624, 0.6475, 0.67125, 0.69075, 0.71975, 0.75225, 0.77475, 0.82025, 
0.849, 0.88625, 0.9095, 0.94375, 0.979, 1.01425, 1.049, 1.0785, 
1.118, 1.146, 1.177, 1.21475, 1.237, 1.2685, 1.30125, 1.327, 
1.3485, 1.37475, 1.389, 1.4115, 1.43875, 1.44975, 1.458, 1.4745, 
1.48675, 1.49525, 1.50325, 1.5165, 1.52775, 1.5345, 1.54675, 
1.5545, 1.564, 1.5675, 1.5725, 1.58175, 1.583, 1.58575, 1.592, 
1.59725, 1.59825), C50 = c(0.1885, 0.23575, 0.27025, 0.30475, 
0.34175, 0.381, 0.41475, 0.44225, 0.478, 0.51325, 0.54375, 0.5625, 
0.5935, 0.625, 0.64875, 0.66425, 0.691, 0.7205, 0.7435, 0.778, 
0.8025, 0.83475, 0.87425, 0.90525, 0.95775, 0.973, 1.0115, 1.04125, 
1.07625, 1.111, 1.13875, 1.17525, 1.20875, 1.241, 1.2665, 1.29175, 
1.31675, 1.3515, 1.377, 1.397, 1.4235, 1.4375, 1.459, 1.48775, 
1.50175, 1.51375, 1.53175, 1.54675, 1.558, 1.5615, 1.5735, 1.58625, 
1.58975, 1.60325, 1.6065, 1.618, 1.6185, 1.6225, 1.632, 1.629, 
1.63025, 1.6355, 1.64, 1.641), C100 = c(0.17925, 0.20525, 0.25425, 
0.29275, 0.3235, 0.35625, 0.3905, 0.421, 0.457, 0.492, 0.51975, 
0.54425, 0.57275, 0.60175, 0.62725, 0.64775, 0.67375, 0.70325, 
0.722, 0.75525, 0.7915, 0.81525, 0.86425, 0.893, 0.93275, 0.959, 
0.998, 1.033, 1.06775, 1.10475, 1.13425, 1.172, 1.20575, 1.237, 
1.26375, 1.28875, 1.31125, 1.34075, 1.36375, 1.384, 1.40725, 
1.41925, 1.437, 1.4595, 1.4715, 1.4825, 1.49925, 1.5155, 1.52875, 
1.53975, 1.557, 1.574, 1.58275, 1.59725, 1.606, 1.6185, 1.622, 
1.6285, 1.6385, 1.6385, 1.642, 1.6485, 1.65225, 1.65475), SDLB = c(0.002487469, 
0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 
0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 
0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 
0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002046338, 0.001870829, 
0.002046338, 0.001870829, 0.001920286, 0.001920286, 0.001920286, 
0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002277608, 0.002277608, 0.002384848, 
0.002692582, 0.002915476, 0.003031089, 0.003269174, 0.003570714, 
0.003937004, 0.004330127, 0.005024938, 0.0065, 0.007189402, 0.009120718, 
0.010839742, 0.012676257, 0.015221284, 0.018267115, 0.021639085, 
0.024217762, 0.027667671, 0.031717503, 0.034477348, 0.03692814, 
0.041051797, 0.043222535, 0.047882669, 0.049173163, 0.055113519, 
0.059838846, 0.061304058, 0.068053288, 0.074583845, 0.079197538, 
0.083175642, 0.089281507), SDC0 = c(0.020314711, 0.013754545, 
0.005165995, 0.005830952, 0.008699856, 0.015215124, 0.020742469, 
0.025426364, 0.029819247, 0.036311155, 0.041394444, 0.04573292, 
0.051742149, 0.058601941, 0.063841111, 0.067569871, 0.072852591, 
0.078477306, 0.078868562, 0.085173353, 0.093169201, 0.095473818, 
0.102008272, 0.092175105, 0.082235941, 0.070162312, 0.067459247, 
0.065738117, 0.065646782, 0.062685724, 0.057273467, 0.053881235, 
0.049393193, 0.045974857, 0.044466279, 0.040904615, 0.039016022, 
0.037033768, 0.035194993, 0.032855745, 0.030881831, 0.029097895, 
0.028437431, 0.028349383, 0.027307279, 0.026129485, 0.024752525, 
0.024262883, 0.024088379, 0.023584953, 0.025377155, 0.026545951, 
0.026752336, 0.02926175, 0.028717373, 0.03132491, 0.029345996, 
0.028411045, 0.029659526, 0.024539509, 0.0245, 0.02440671, 0.024768932, 
0.02368016), SDC10 = c(0.013143439, 0.011605494, 0.01498958, 
0.016515145, 0.024824383, 0.03482456, 0.040170729, 0.047283057, 
0.053110145, 0.058383966, 0.059434838, 0.061808171, 0.066640828, 
0.070881944, 0.073172314, 0.072682099, 0.075174381, 0.078445443, 
0.077483466, 0.081049368, 0.08525953, 0.084842501, 0.09012318, 
0.088075252, 0.086615169, 0.08116149, 0.079564439, 0.079937476, 
0.072706172, 0.070938354, 0.066417242, 0.064183331, 0.058836107, 
0.054974426, 0.049689033, 0.044528081, 0.045751366, 0.038693507, 
0.03278338, 0.030531746, 0.024304063, 0.020054613, 0.014515078, 
0.008642193, 0.012577261, 0.015247951, 0.016469669, 0.019817921, 
0.023155723, 0.025410382, 0.025124689, 0.026630575, 0.02725344, 
0.027860142, 0.027444262, 0.029054905, 0.029046299, 0.029371542, 
0.030392228, 0.027856777, 0.02723394, 0.026617663, 0.028864987, 
0.026947866), SDC20 = c(0.021844622, 0.011863811, 0.021569655, 
0.027878083, 0.036400549, 0.043985793, 0.049043348, 0.053368998, 
0.056493362, 0.057823006, 0.060155528, 0.062455484, 0.065731937, 
0.068765453, 0.071641468, 0.069745968, 0.069456821, 0.071628818, 
0.068896208, 0.070314917, 0.072223178, 0.06884902, 0.073506377, 
0.074545288, 0.077483466, 0.07047872, 0.070796804, 0.069061567, 
0.068100569, 0.067412907, 0.06425535, 0.060881032, 0.061899111, 
0.063035704, 0.050938075, 0.051200586, 0.046246621, 0.045844165, 
0.043611925, 0.040709336, 0.042522788, 0.041587258, 0.040332989, 
0.04293236, 0.043083495, 0.042148547, 0.042127782, 0.042938182, 
0.041336273, 0.03971382, 0.040782962, 0.03982697, 0.037646381, 
0.039168706, 0.035780581, 0.038542185, 0.035344731, 0.035089172, 
0.036485442, 0.033860006, 0.033484138, 0.034734709, 0.034909705, 
0.033221793), SDC50 = c(0.017670597, 0.011453711, 0.013663363, 
0.020522853, 0.029928039, 0.038059164, 0.043894049, 0.049119115, 
0.052139237, 0.055571463, 0.059289017, 0.06082968, 0.064863318, 
0.069079664, 0.07371355, 0.076185218, 0.081298831, 0.084328228, 
0.090946413, 0.100169856, 0.094309331, 0.104659866, 0.09936643, 
0.102738442, 0.116368757, 0.110609674, 0.106361412, 0.101233332, 
0.094078093, 0.092668765, 0.089923231, 0.090198046, 0.087650941, 
0.085565764, 0.081671598, 0.075204305, 0.073206472, 0.071765242, 
0.067944831, 0.06555532, 0.06326729, 0.057081083, 0.053740115, 
0.053765114, 0.052470825, 0.048509664, 0.046078059, 0.04099009, 
0.034532593, 0.030368569, 0.025352515, 0.023166517, 0.022708754, 
0.021264701, 0.020657928, 0.021342446, 0.022017039, 0.021937411, 
0.020211383, 0.018641352, 0.017795716, 0.017867568, 0.017248188, 
0.017535678), SDC100 = c(0.010062306, 0.011053845, 0.026570661, 
0.008093207, 0.006609652, 0.012968712, 0.020168044, 0.022498611, 
0.024418231, 0.022653642, 0.019765816, 0.015206906, 0.01662077, 
0.014463316, 0.015974589, 0.018179659, 0.021914607, 0.027390692, 
0.031464265, 0.038629652, 0.051823619, 0.051373023, 0.052394537, 
0.047877448, 0.052471421, 0.049786419, 0.047267193, 0.049332418, 
0.049001913, 0.044885967, 0.035981766, 0.028486839, 0.026310644, 
0.025913317, 0.026808348, 0.024924887, 0.020141686, 0.019600702, 
0.019447043, 0.018090053, 0.01662077, 0.018471261, 0.025666126, 
0.026873546, 0.02078912, 0.016976086, 0.017282578, 0.019422925, 
0.021229402, 0.023140873, 0.027206387, 0.032653484, 0.03911122, 
0.041117971, 0.040798284, 0.036656343, 0.030752032, 0.026776856, 
0.019904459, 0.010012492, 0.005448624, 0.015122417, 0.027901613, 
0.042408726)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -64L))
```

```
Test <- B690DNaseI %>%
  pivot_longer(!Time,
               names_to = c("Concentration", ".value"),
               names_pattern = c("([[:alnum:]]+)_([[:alpha:]]+)")) %>%
  rename_with(~ paste("SD_", ., sep = ""), !c(Time, Concentration))
```

This code worked for previous data set, but not this one

The gather function did not work either

```
PB690 <- B690DNaseI %>% gather(SD_column, SD_value, starts_with("SD"))
```

---

### Minimal input

```
small = structure(list(Time = c("00:15", "00:30", "00:45"), LB = c(0.08775, 
0.0875, 0.0875), C0 = c(0.16925, 0.20775, 0.23975), C10 = c(0.16925, 
0.20775, 0.23975), SDLB = c(0.002487469, 0.002061553, 0.002061553
), SDC0 = c(0.020314711, 0.013754545, 0.005165995), SDC10 = c(0.013143439, 
0.011605494, 0.01498958)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
small
#    Time      LB      C0     C10        SDLB        SDC0      SDC10
# 1 00:15 0.08775 0.16925 0.16925 0.002487469 0.020314711 0.01314344
# 2 00:30 0.08750 0.20775 0.20775 0.002061553 0.013754545 0.01160549
# 3 00:45 0.08750 0.23975 0.23975 0.002061553 0.005165995 0.01498958
```

Comment: So, at a glance your `names_pattern` is looking for column names with two parts, separated by an `_`. In your sample data, none of the column names have `_`. I think if you use a consistent naming pattern like the dataset that worked, the same code will work.

Comment: It's not perfectly clear to me what your desired output is for the sample input. Your question would be much improved if you made your sample input **minimal** - just a few rows instead of 64 and maybe drop some columns, and then you could also show what is the desired output for that sample input. I've edited a **minimal** example into your question named `small`--could you please show the desired output for that `small` input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that you want a mean and SD column for each Concentration at each Time. You could do this by first renaming your columns systematically and *then* using `pivot_longer`

```r
library(tidyverse)

B690DNaseI %>% 
  rename_with(~ifelse(substr(.x, 1, 2) == "SD", 
                      gsub("SD", "SD_", .x), paste0("mean_", .x)),
              .cols = -1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1, names_sep = "_", names_to = c(".value", "Concentration"))
#> # A tibble: 384 x 4
#>    Time  Concentration   mean      SD
#>    <chr> <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 00:15 LB            0.0878 0.00249
#>  2 00:15 C0            0.169  0.0203 
#>  3 00:15 C10           0.169  0.0131 
#>  4 00:15 C20           0.200  0.0218 
#>  5 00:15 C50           0.188  0.0177 
#>  6 00:15 C100          0.179  0.0101 
#>  7 00:30 LB            0.0875 0.00206
#>  8 00:30 C0            0.208  0.0138 
#>  9 00:30 C10           0.208  0.0116 
#> 10 00:30 C20           0.228  0.0119 
#> # i 374 more rows
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much! I started working in R 6 months ago and find it a bit difficult sometimes, but I'm learning each day, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this.  `pivot_wider` can definitely do the job, but you need to properly prefix the mean and sd columns first.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- structure(
  list(
    Time = c("00:15", "00:30", "00:45", "01:00", "01:15", 
             "01:30", "01:45", "02:00", "02:15", "02:30", "02:45", "03:00", 
             "03:15", "03:30", "03:45", "04:00", "04:15", "04:30", "04:45", 
             "05:00", "05:15", "05:30", "05:45", "06:00", "06:15", "06:30", 
             "06:45", "07:00", "07:15", "07:30", "07:45", "08:00", "08:15", 
             "08:30", "08:45", "09:00", "09:15", "09:30", "09:45", "10:00", 
             "10:15", "10:30", "10:45", "11:00", "11:15", "11:30", "11:45", 
             "12:00", "12:15", "12:30", "12:45", "13:00", "13:15", "13:30", 
             "13:45", "14:00", "14:15", "14:30", "14:45", "15:00", "15:15", 
             "15:30", "15:45", "16:00"), 
    LB = c(0.08775, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 
           0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 
           0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.0875, 0.08775, 
           0.088, 0.08775, 0.088, 0.08825, 0.08825, 0.08825, 0.0885, 0.0885, 
           0.08875, 0.08875, 0.08925, 0.0895, 0.09, 0.09025, 0.09075, 0.0915, 
           0.092, 0.0935, 0.0945, 0.0955, 0.09725, 0.09925, 0.101, 0.10175, 
           0.10525, 0.10825, 0.1105, 0.113, 0.117, 0.121, 0.12375, 0.12625, 
           0.1305, 0.13275, 0.1375, 0.139, 0.145, 0.15025, 0.15175, 0.1585, 
           0.1655, 0.1705, 0.17425, 0.18125), 
    C0 = c(0.16925, 0.20775, 0.23975, 
           0.268, 0.29225, 0.316, 0.3385, 0.359, 0.38125, 0.401, 0.423, 
           0.444, 0.4645, 0.48725, 0.51125, 0.53525, 0.563, 0.59825, 0.6375, 
           0.682, 0.729, 0.7835, 0.84725, 0.8935, 0.9555, 0.9975, 1.0475, 
           1.094, 1.141, 1.19, 1.2285, 1.27225, 1.30925, 1.34475, 1.3725, 
           1.39875, 1.4255, 1.457, 1.47825, 1.495, 1.51825, 1.52675, 1.54475, 
           1.57025, 1.57975, 1.5865, 1.60025, 1.60975, 1.6155, 1.6145, 1.625, 
           1.63225, 1.63125, 1.6385, 1.63625, 1.6435, 1.63825, 1.63925, 
           1.64625, 1.64225, 1.6405, 1.64475, 1.648, 1.6465), 
    C10 = c(0.16925, 
            0.20775, 0.23975, 0.268, 0.29225, 0.316, 0.3385, 0.359, 0.38125, 
            0.401, 0.423, 0.444, 0.4645, 0.48725, 0.51125, 0.53525, 0.563, 
            0.59825, 0.6375, 0.682, 0.729, 0.7835, 0.84725, 0.8935, 0.9555, 
            0.9975, 1.0475, 1.094, 1.141, 1.19, 1.2285, 1.27225, 1.30925, 
            1.34475, 1.3725, 1.39875, 1.4255, 1.457, 1.47825, 1.495, 1.51825, 
            1.52675, 1.54475, 1.57025, 1.57975, 1.5865, 1.60025, 1.60975, 
            1.6155, 1.6145, 1.625, 1.63225, 1.63125, 1.6385, 1.63625, 1.6435, 
            1.63825, 1.63925, 1.64625, 1.64225, 1.6405, 1.64475, 1.648, 1.6465
    ), 
    C20 = c(0.19975, 0.2285, 0.2555, 0.28525, 0.318, 0.3545, 0.3865, 
            0.4155, 0.45, 0.482, 0.50825, 0.52975, 0.55625, 0.58325, 0.604, 
            0.624, 0.6475, 0.67125, 0.69075, 0.71975, 0.75225, 0.77475, 0.82025, 
            0.849, 0.88625, 0.9095, 0.94375, 0.979, 1.01425, 1.049, 1.0785, 
            1.118, 1.146, 1.177, 1.21475, 1.237, 1.2685, 1.30125, 1.327, 
            1.3485, 1.37475, 1.389, 1.4115, 1.43875, 1.44975, 1.458, 1.4745, 
            1.48675, 1.49525, 1.50325, 1.5165, 1.52775, 1.5345, 1.54675, 
            1.5545, 1.564, 1.5675, 1.5725, 1.58175, 1.583, 1.58575, 1.592, 
            1.59725, 1.59825), 
    C50 = c(0.1885, 0.23575, 0.27025, 0.30475, 
            0.34175, 0.381, 0.41475, 0.44225, 0.478, 0.51325, 0.54375, 0.5625, 
            0.5935, 0.625, 0.64875, 0.66425, 0.691, 0.7205, 0.7435, 0.778, 
            0.8025, 0.83475, 0.87425, 0.90525, 0.95775, 0.973, 1.0115, 1.04125, 
            1.07625, 1.111, 1.13875, 1.17525, 1.20875, 1.241, 1.2665, 1.29175, 
            1.31675, 1.3515, 1.377, 1.397, 1.4235, 1.4375, 1.459, 1.48775, 
            1.50175, 1.51375, 1.53175, 1.54675, 1.558, 1.5615, 1.5735, 1.58625, 
            1.58975, 1.60325, 1.6065, 1.618, 1.6185, 1.6225, 1.632, 1.629, 
            1.63025, 1.6355, 1.64, 1.641), 
    C100 = c(0.17925, 0.20525, 0.25425, 
             0.29275, 0.3235, 0.35625, 0.3905, 0.421, 0.457, 0.492, 0.51975, 
             0.54425, 0.57275, 0.60175, 0.62725, 0.64775, 0.67375, 0.70325, 
             0.722, 0.75525, 0.7915, 0.81525, 0.86425, 0.893, 0.93275, 0.959, 
             0.998, 1.033, 1.06775, 1.10475, 1.13425, 1.172, 1.20575, 1.237, 
             1.26375, 1.28875, 1.31125, 1.34075, 1.36375, 1.384, 1.40725, 
             1.41925, 1.437, 1.4595, 1.4715, 1.4825, 1.49925, 1.5155, 1.52875, 
             1.53975, 1.557, 1.574, 1.58275, 1.59725, 1.606, 1.6185, 1.622, 
             1.6285, 1.6385, 1.6385, 1.642, 1.6485, 1.65225, 1.65475), 
    SDLB = c(0.002487469, 
             0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 
             0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 
             0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 
             0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002046338, 0.001870829, 
             0.002046338, 0.001870829, 0.001920286, 0.001920286, 0.001920286, 
             0.002061553, 0.002061553, 0.002277608, 0.002277608, 0.002384848, 
             0.002692582, 0.002915476, 0.003031089, 0.003269174, 0.003570714, 
             0.003937004, 0.004330127, 0.005024938, 0.0065, 0.007189402, 0.009120718, 
             0.010839742, 0.012676257, 0.015221284, 0.018267115, 0.021639085, 
             0.024217762, 0.027667671, 0.031717503, 0.034477348, 0.03692814, 
             0.041051797, 0.043222535, 0.047882669, 0.049173163, 0.055113519, 
             0.059838846, 0.061304058, 0.068053288, 0.074583845, 0.079197538, 
             0.083175642, 0.089281507), 
    SDC0 = c(0.020314711, 0.013754545, 
             0.005165995, 0.005830952, 0.008699856, 0.015215124, 0.020742469, 
             0.025426364, 0.029819247, 0.036311155, 0.041394444, 0.04573292, 
             0.051742149, 0.058601941, 0.063841111, 0.067569871, 0.072852591, 
             0.078477306, 0.078868562, 0.085173353, 0.093169201, 0.095473818, 
             0.102008272, 0.092175105, 0.082235941, 0.070162312, 0.067459247, 
             0.065738117, 0.065646782, 0.062685724, 0.057273467, 0.053881235, 
             0.049393193, 0.045974857, 0.044466279, 0.040904615, 0.039016022, 
             0.037033768, 0.035194993, 0.032855745, 0.030881831, 0.029097895, 
             0.028437431, 0.028349383, 0.027307279, 0.026129485, 0.024752525, 
             0.024262883, 0.024088379, 0.023584953, 0.025377155, 0.026545951, 
             0.026752336, 0.02926175, 0.028717373, 0.03132491, 0.029345996, 
             0.028411045, 0.029659526, 0.024539509, 0.0245, 0.02440671, 0.024768932, 
             0.02368016), 
    SDC10 = c(0.013143439, 0.011605494, 0.01498958, 
              0.016515145, 0.024824383, 0.03482456, 0.040170729, 0.047283057, 
              0.053110145, 0.058383966, 0.059434838, 0.061808171, 0.066640828, 
              0.070881944, 0.073172314, 0.072682099, 0.075174381, 0.078445443, 
              0.077483466, 0.081049368, 0.08525953, 0.084842501, 0.09012318, 
              0.088075252, 0.086615169, 0.08116149, 0.079564439, 0.079937476, 
              0.072706172, 0.070938354, 0.066417242, 0.064183331, 0.058836107, 
              0.054974426, 0.049689033, 0.044528081, 0.045751366, 0.038693507, 
              0.03278338, 0.030531746, 0.024304063, 0.020054613, 0.014515078, 
              0.008642193, 0.012577261, 0.015247951, 0.016469669, 0.019817921, 
              0.023155723, 0.025410382, 0.025124689, 0.026630575, 0.02725344, 
              0.027860142, 0.027444262, 0.029054905, 0.029046299, 0.029371542, 
              0.030392228, 0.027856777, 0.02723394, 0.026617663, 0.028864987, 
              0.026947866), 
    SDC20 = c(0.021844622, 0.011863811, 0.021569655, 
              0.027878083, 0.036400549, 0.043985793, 0.049043348, 0.053368998, 
              0.056493362, 0.057823006, 0.060155528, 0.062455484, 0.065731937, 
              0.068765453, 0.071641468, 0.069745968, 0.069456821, 0.071628818, 
              0.068896208, 0.070314917, 0.072223178, 0.06884902, 0.073506377, 
              0.074545288, 0.077483466, 0.07047872, 0.070796804, 0.069061567, 
              0.068100569, 0.067412907, 0.06425535, 0.060881032, 0.061899111, 
              0.063035704, 0.050938075, 0.051200586, 0.046246621, 0.045844165, 
              0.043611925, 0.040709336, 0.042522788, 0.041587258, 0.040332989, 
              0.04293236, 0.043083495, 0.042148547, 0.042127782, 0.042938182, 
              0.041336273, 0.03971382, 0.040782962, 0.03982697, 0.037646381, 
              0.039168706, 0.035780581, 0.038542185, 0.035344731, 0.035089172, 
              0.036485442, 0.033860006, 0.033484138, 0.034734709, 0.034909705, 
              0.033221793), 
    SDC50 = c(0.017670597, 0.011453711, 0.013663363, 
              0.020522853, 0.029928039, 0.038059164, 0.043894049, 0.049119115, 
              0.052139237, 0.055571463, 0.059289017, 0.06082968, 0.064863318, 
              0.069079664, 0.07371355, 0.076185218, 0.081298831, 0.084328228, 
              0.090946413, 0.100169856, 0.094309331, 0.104659866, 0.09936643, 
              0.102738442, 0.116368757, 0.110609674, 0.106361412, 0.101233332, 
              0.094078093, 0.092668765, 0.089923231, 0.090198046, 0.087650941, 
              0.085565764, 0.081671598, 0.075204305, 0.073206472, 0.071765242, 
              0.067944831, 0.06555532, 0.06326729, 0.057081083, 0.053740115, 
              0.053765114, 0.052470825, 0.048509664, 0.046078059, 0.04099009, 
              0.034532593, 0.030368569, 0.025352515, 0.023166517, 0.022708754, 
              0.021264701, 0.020657928, 0.021342446, 0.022017039, 0.021937411, 
              0.020211383, 0.018641352, 0.017795716, 0.017867568, 0.017248188, 
              0.017535678), 
    SDC100 = c(0.010062306, 0.011053845, 0.026570661, 
               0.008093207, 0.006609652, 0.012968712, 0.020168044, 0.022498611, 
               0.024418231, 0.022653642, 0.019765816, 0.015206906, 0.01662077, 
               0.014463316, 0.015974589, 0.018179659, 0.021914607, 0.027390692, 
               0.031464265, 0.038629652, 0.051823619, 0.051373023, 0.052394537, 
               0.047877448, 0.052471421, 0.049786419, 0.047267193, 0.049332418, 
               0.049001913, 0.044885967, 0.035981766, 0.028486839, 0.026310644, 
               0.025913317, 0.026808348, 0.024924887, 0.020141686, 0.019600702, 
               0.019447043, 0.018090053, 0.01662077, 0.018471261, 0.025666126, 
               0.026873546, 0.02078912, 0.016976086, 0.017282578, 0.019422925, 
               0.021229402, 0.023140873, 0.027206387, 0.032653484, 0.03911122, 
               0.041117971, 0.040798284, 0.036656343, 0.030752032, 0.026776856, 
               0.019904459, 0.010012492, 0.005448624, 0.015122417, 0.027901613, 
               0.042408726)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -64L))

dat |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  rename_with(.fn = ~str_c("mean_", .), .cols = c(-Time, -starts_with("SD"))) |> 
  rename_with(.fn = ~str_replace(., "SD", "sd_"), .cols = c(starts_with("SD"))) |> 
  pivot_longer(-Time, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("name", "measure")) |> 
  pivot_wider()
#> # A tibble: 384 × 4
#>    Time  measure   mean      sd
#>    <chr> <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 00:15 LB      0.0878 0.00249
#>  2 00:15 C0      0.169  0.0203 
#>  3 00:15 C10     0.169  0.0131 
#>  4 00:15 C20     0.200  0.0218 
#>  5 00:15 C50     0.188  0.0177 
#>  6 00:15 C100    0.179  0.0101 
#>  7 00:30 LB      0.0875 0.00206
#>  8 00:30 C0      0.208  0.0138 
#>  9 00:30 C10     0.208  0.0116 
#> 10 00:30 C20     0.228  0.0119 
#> # ℹ 374 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you so much for taking the time to help, I appreciate it so much, I'm still learning how to work R, so this was very helpful!